# Numpy Array to ArcGIS GRID gives ValueError?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.4, numpy, valueerror

I have a numpy array saved to disk ( the numpy array is a depth image from a Kinect 360) and I want to convert that numpy array to an ESRI GRID. I have the simple code below to accomplish that task but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\gTemp\Text-1.py", line 4, in myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myarray,(0.0,0.0),1.0, 1.0, -99999.0 )

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy__init__.py", line 2299, in NumPyArrayToRaster return _NumPyArrayToRaster(*args, **kwargs) ValueError: Argument in_array: A two or three dimensional NumPy array is required.
```

I am new to numpy and do not understand why I am getting this error. I am using ArcGIS 10.4

```
import arcpy
import numpy
myarray = r"E:\depthtester2.npy"
myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myarray,(0.0,0.0),1.0, 1.0, -99999.0 )
myRaster.save("E:\deptht")
```

Comment: myarray is a string, it needs to be converted (loaded) into a NumPy array to be used in this function. What is in the file E:\depthtester2.npy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `r"E:\depthtester2.npy"` is a saved array, use [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) to avoid the `ValueError`, and as noted in the comments, you need to pass a point object to `NumPyArrayToRaster` or you'll get a `TypeError`.

```
myarray = numpy.load(r"E:\depthtester2.npy")
myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myarray,arcpy.Point(0.0,0.0),1.0, 1.0, -99999.0 )
```

Comment: Also, looking at the docs http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/NumPyArrayToRaster/03q30000007q000000/ parameter 2 should be an arcpy.Point object, making the line look like myRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myarray,arcpy.Point(0.0,0.0),1.0, 1.0, -99999.0 ) otherwise you'll get another ValueError.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson, actually, you'll get a TypeError, but noted and I've updated my answer.