# Numpy Array to ArcGIS GRID gives dimensional error with masked array

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster, numpy, esri-grid-format

I have an 84x73 masked numpy array to load into ArcGIS (version 10.3.1, Windows 8.1).

To overcome the fact that [Masked Numpy arrays cannot be saved to .npy file as of yet](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.tofile.html), I am saving my array from Jupyter as

```
import numpy

myarray.dump("C:\MyName\MyFolder\Array_to_raster.npy")
```

Then, I load this array in ArcGIS, as suggested at [Numpy Array to ArcGIS GRID gives ValueError?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207365):

```
myarray = numpy.load(r"C:\MyName\MyFolder\Array_to_raster.npy")
```

And then I attempt to create a raster out of it as

```
arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster (myarray, arcpy.Point(447328.4200,357465.6840), 1500, 1500, -2147483648)
```

where `-2147483648` is the `fill_value` of my masked cells.

However, this throws an error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 2292, in NumPyArrayToRaster
    return _NumPyArrayToRaster(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Argument in_array: A two or three dimensional NumPy array is required.
```

But as I said, I already have a 2D array:

```
>>> myarray.shape
(84, 73)
```

How can I create the raster out of `myarray`?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256173/converting-numpy-array-to-raster-with-arcpy?noredirect=1&lq=1 and for good measure https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256173/converting-numpy-array-to-raster-with-arcpy?noredirect=1&lq=1